# What happens if I delete Meta Store of Hive from My SQL Server?

Tags: hive

What happens if I delete Meta Store of Hive from My SQL Server? Please provide me the details for Managed Table and External Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lose the metadata - that's all. **The data will be unaffected.**  So you can then simply re-run the scripts that define your tables. This is true for both managed and external tables.

So the deletion (and re-creation) may be a good way for you to clean up a potentially corrupted metastore.